# Android share menu item

Tags: java, android

I have a codeof share item in menu which was working , I wanted to add it to a new app and I get an error "cannot cast android.view.ActopnProvider to android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"
this is the code:

```
MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);
        mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();
        String playStoreLink = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" +
                getPackageName();
        String yourShareText = "Install this app " + playStoreLink;
        Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(this)
                .setType("text/plain").setText(yourShareText).getIntent();
        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
```

what is the problem?

Comment: see my below answer, if any query let me know

Answer (score 1):

In new app you probably use AppCompat backport of the action bar so you have to use

```
      android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider
```

instead

```
      android.widget.ShareActionProvider
```

Comment: Thats the item xml: <item
        android:id="@+id/share"
        android:title=""        app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"        app:showAsAction="always"/>

Answer (score 0):

Remove this import

> import android.view.ActionProvider